# JAVA - Tomcat 5 Application connecting to Web Service using HTTPS, while Tomcat 7 Application does not

Tags: java, ssl, https, tomcat7, tomcat5

We have this scenario where an application on a particular server using `Tomcat 5` (`JDK 1.4`) can successfully connect with a web service using `HTTPS` and the same application using `Tomcat 7` (`JDK 1.7`) on another server fails to connect to this web service. Having said that, the `Tomcat 7` application is able to connect to the web service using `port 8080` and `HTTP`. The problem seems to be when connecting with `HTTPS`. The error is the following:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.ByteArrayRequestEntity.writeRequest(ByteArrayRequestEntity.java:89)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:495)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:993)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:324)
    at Pdf.HtmlToPdf.GeneratePdf(HtmlToPdf.java:42)
    at Crm.CAA.CaaTest.generatePdf(CaaTest.java:584)
    at Crm.CAA.CaaTest.GeneratePdf(CaaTest.java:194)
    at Crm.Servlets.CaaPdfOutputter.doPost(CaaPdfOutputter.java:53)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at Filters.ExampleFilter.doFilter(ExampleFilter.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 50 more
```

I was doing some research and noticed that the cacerts file might be behind this, however, could it still be the case since the Tomcat 5 application is working, and only the `Tomcat 7` one is not?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore

Comment: @Michael - This scenario is different. The issue is slightly different since one particular application is connecting, while the other is not.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the root cause of this problem is that when you are running the newer version (tc7, jdk1.7) you application is unable to find the certificate store.

Are you specifying where the certificates are stored in you java code? Or anywhere else for that matter?

If so you may be doing it in a Java1.4 way that has been updated in later versions.

The default certificate store for java is {$JAVA_HOME}/lib/security/cacerts
If your certificate is not being stored here, then this may be your problem. **This store is per java version** so this would explain why the older version is working while the new version is not.

(This is covered in the post linked to by Michael)

If this doesn't fix the problem, then it would be useful if you could post some more information about how you are connecting (i.e. the java code which is throwing the exception...). Also your platform would be useful.

Hope this helps